# Sitecore commerce server: migration data from older verion

Tags: sitecore, commerce, commerceserver

I have installed Sitecore Commerce Server(ver. 11.3) and I need to migrate all data from the previous version of Commerce Server(it is 11.2). Just back up and restore doesn't work, I got following error message:
"Application is not compatible with '11.200' version of 'Product Catalog' resource. Expected resource version is '11.300'"

Also, I tried to follow section "Breaking Changes" from this manual: http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS81/releasenotes/en-us/index.html , but it doesn't help, too.

What are the best practices of upgrading Sitecore Commerce Server?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what data you need to migrate from 11.2 to 11.3 - is it transaction data (baskets + orders), catalog data and/or profile data?